Lotus Script - Upload pdf file into API - format corrupted - Pdf to binary then string
i have to upload a PDF file in a multi-part form-data way :
filePath =louidoc.FieldGetText("PdfFile")

' Generate a unique boundary for the multipart form data
boundary = "---------------------------" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        
' Construct the multipart/form-data request body
formData = "--" & boundary & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""id_requisito""" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & idRequisito & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "--" & boundary & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & filePath & """" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "Content-Type: application/pdf" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& **FileToStringv2(filePath)** & Chr(13) & Chr(10) _
& "--" & boundary & "--" & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
        
' Set the Content-Type header for the request
contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary

' Set the Content-Type header for the request
contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
        
' Create an instance of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        
' Open a POST request to the specified URL
xmlHttp.open "POST", url, False
        
' Set the Content-Type header
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", contentType
        
' Send the multipart/form-data request body
xmlHttp.send formData


OPENIA says i have to parse the PDF file into a string in order to upload it :
Function FileToString(filePath As String) As String
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileSize As Long
    
    ' Attempt to open the file
    On Error Resume Next
    fileNum = Freefile()
    Open filePath For Binary As fileNum
    If Err <> 0 Then
        FileToString = "" ' Return empty string if unable to open the file
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    
    ' Determine the size of the file
    fileSize = Filelen(filePath)
    
    ' Read the entire content of the file into a string
    If fileSize > 0 Then
        fileContent = Space$(fileSize)+1 ' Create a string buffer of the file size
        stringlen = Len(fileContent)
        Get #fileNum, , fileContent
    Else
        fileContent = "" ' File is empty or size is zero
    End If
    
    ' Close the file
    Close fileNum
    
    ' Return the file content as a string
    FileToString = fileContent
End Function

Get #fileNum gets an error
if i code : 
' Use LOF to find the file length, and Input$ to read the entire file into the string veriable izFile.
    fileContent$ = Input$(Lof(fileNum%), fileNum%)
    Close fileNum
    
    fileNum% = Freefile()
    Open filePath For Input As fileNum%
    vFileContent = Input(Lof(fileNum%), fileNum%)
    Close fileNum

the API receives the PDF but it's corrupted, i don't know if there is another way to upload a file with lotus script or another way to parse it into a string, thanks in advance

Agree with previous comment: You need to base64 encode the string. Also, you are calling FileToString() but the code you posted is FileToString()

thanks, the API doesn't receive files in base64 format, i'm trying to build a JAR file or Java agent to do the parsing stuff but i don't know how to return the string value.

For binary data, I believe that your fileContent variable should be a variant, and the return type for your FileToString function should be a variant. I believe your data will be read into an array of bytes, rather than a string of characters. (You should check that in the debugger.)
And I think you will need to change your formData variable to a byte array as well, and build it using array access operations rather than string concatenation. That's the best way to assure that your data faithfully represents the contents of the binary file in the http post data.
